# Firebase NoSQL Data modeling - Like counter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm currently learning Firebase/NoSQL database modeling. I just ended watching the [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), but I still have few doubts.

Let's say I'm creating Instagram-styled app where users could share their photos and each user could like each photo.

So I would like to achieve two things:
1. Know which user has liked which photo. (So only one like per user for photo)
2. How many likes each photo has.

My current database looks like this:

```
{
  "images": {
    "100": {
      "imageUrl": "../../image.png",
    },
    "101": {
      "imageUrl": "../../image.png",
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "200": {
      "name": "user1"
    },
    "201": {
      "name": "user2"
    }
  },
  "likes": {
    "100": 1,
    "101": 2
  },
  "likesPerUser": {
    "200": {
      "100": "true"
    },
    "201": {
      "100": "true",
      "101": "true"
    }
  }
  "imagesPerUser": {
    "200": {
        "101": "true"
    },
    "201": {
        "100": "true"
    }
}
```

My question is related to the counter, that counts how many likes each photo has. Would the best practice be that I have them as their own "root"-object (current model) OR to create key-value pair for "likes" under the photo (and maybe do the same for authorID)?

Answer (score 2):

[This Firebase Sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count) recommends having the counter(`likes_count`) under each post. And also having a node(`likes`) with a list/[lookup](https://youtu.be/i1n9Kw3AORw?t=2m22s) . Like this:

```
"images": {
    "100": {
      "imageUrl": "../../image.png",
      "likes_count":2,
      "likes":{
        "200":true,
        "201":true
      }
    },
    "101": {
      "imageUrl": "../../image.png",
      "likes_count":1,
      "likes":{
        "201":true
      }
    }
}
```

This way you'll ensure only one like per user, because keys must be unique under a Firebase Realtime Database node, and the user ids are used as keys under the `likes_count` node. You can also know which users liked the photo because their uids are there. And obviously, you can see how many likes a photo has by accessing the counter.

Comment: Cheers! So basically I could use this same "likes_count" structure to track following/followers of each user? "follower_count / followers" and "following_count / following"

Comment: I don't see why not ;)